# identical word alignment using for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, alignment, sentence

I'm trying to align words from two list

```
sentence1 = ['boy','motorcycle','people','play']
sentence2 = ['run','boy','people','boy','play','play']
```

and this is my codes :

```
def identicalWordsIndex(self, sentence1, sentence2):
    identical_index = []
    for i in xrange(len(sentence1)):
        for j in xrange(len(sentence2)):
            if sentence1[i] == sentence2[j]:
                idenNew1 = [i,j]
                identical_index.append(idenNew1)
            if sentence2[j] == sentence1[i]:
                idenNew2 = [j,i]
                identical_index.append(idenNew2)
    return identical_index
```

what i'm trying to do is get the index number of align words from sentence1 and sentence2.

1st is the aligned words index from sentence1 towards sentence2.
2nd is the aligned words index from sentence2 towards sentence1.

but the result from the codes above is like this :

```
1st : [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 3], [3, 0], [2, 2], [2, 2], [3, 4], [4, 3], [3, 5], [5, 3]]
2nd : [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 3], [3, 0], [2, 2], [2, 2], [3, 4], [4, 3], [3, 5], [5, 3]]
```

what I expect from the result is like this :

```
1st : [[0,1],[2,2],[3,4]]
2nd : [[1,0],[2,2],[3,0],[4,3],[5,3]]
```

anyone can solve? thanks

Comment: `len(sentence1, sentence2)` should return a Type error as the `len` accepts one argument. Also your code has an `IndentationError`.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm typo because I retyped it again from my source codes. I have edited, but the result is still the same

Comment: the result doesn't change into what i expect. it is still the same result as my codes above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add breaks. Try this:

```
sentence1 = ['boy','motorcycle','people','play']
sentence2 = ['run','boy','people','boy','play','play']
identical_index = []

def identicalWordsIndex( sentence1, sentence2):
    identical_index = []
    for i in xrange(len(sentence1)):
        for j in xrange(len(sentence2)):
            if sentence1[i] == sentence2[j]:
                idenNew1 = [i,j]
                identical_index.append(idenNew1)
                break
    return identical_index

print (identicalWordsIndex(sentence1, sentence2))
print (identicalWordsIndex(sentence2, sentence1))
```

Prints:

[[0, 1], [2, 2], [3, 4]]

[[1, 0], [2, 2], [3, 0], [4, 3], [5, 3]]

Comment: The second `if` is useless, it's the same as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution using `for loops`:

```
a = ['boy','motorcycle','people','play']
b = ['run','boy','people','boy','play','play']

def align_ab(a, b):
    indexed = []
    for k,v in enumerate(a):
        try:
            i = b.index(v)
            indexed.append([k,i])
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return indexed
# Align a words from b
print(align_ab(a,b))
# Align b words from a
print(align_ab(b,a))
```

Output:

```
>>> [[0, 1], [2, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> [[1, 0], [2, 2], [3, 0], [4, 3], [5, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this suits you. At the last two lines, you can just swap the arguments to get what you want.

```
sentence1 = ['boy','motorcycle','people','play']
sentence2 = ['run','boy','people','boy','play','play']

def identicalWordsIndex(sentence1, sentence2):
    identical_index = []
    for i in range(len(sentence1)):
        for j in range(len(sentence2)):
            if sentence1[i] == sentence2[j]:
            identical_index.append([i, j])
                break
    return identical_index

print(identicalWordsIndex(sentence1, sentence2))
print(identicalWordsIndex(sentence2, sentence1))
```

output:

```
>>>[[0, 1], [2, 2], [3, 4]]
>>>[[1, 0], [2, 2], [3, 0], [4, 3], [5, 3]]
```